# How to use ffmpeg to convert video to avi without compression?

Tags: ffmpeg

I am using this command to convert a .mp4 video file to avi:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 video.avi
```

But the .avi file I got is compressed with FMP4 and I can't open it in VirtualDub.

How can I create an .avi file that has no compression at all? Or with a very easy loseles codec that Virtualdub can understand? Or with DivX one-pass?

Comment: If the input video is encoded, it might be decoded into a certain format. But avi is a container - which holds streams (encoded or not). So the command is wrong and the OP does not seem to accept it. He needs to decode the h264 into a format that only contains I frames (and thus are not "encoded") . He might look at [this](https://superuser.com/questions/347433/how-to-create-an-uncompressed-avi-from-a-series-of-1000s-of-png-images-using-ff) and accept that his assumptions may be wrong

Comment: @kanehekili - Of course the command is wrong and of course I accept it. It is not working for me and that's why I am here, to ask for a better command. I did not come here to post an answer, I am here to ask a question. Sorry but your friend was posting useless true stuff.

Comment: @kanehekili - the solution you linked works. If you want to post an answer with it then I will vote it up and accept it. Thanks!

Comment: There are a couple of lossless audio and video codecs supported by the ancient avi container: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_video_container_formats . However I would doubt the wisdom of using older software that will only accept avi files as input. Is there not a forked version of Virtualdub http://www.virtualdub2.com/ which is much more flexible in all areas? This is a Windows application too I believe...

Answer (score 2):

Since the input stream is encoded `ffmpeg` has to convert it into a "lossless" codec. That is a codec that only contains I-Frames. Avi is a container of streams and thus does not know anything about "converting".

`ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -c:a copy -c:v ayuv output.avi`

should do the trick, where "ayuv" is one of the possible codecs as example .

More infos [here](https://superuser.com/questions/347433/how-to-create-an-uncompressed-avi-from-a-series-of-1000s-of-png-images-using-ff)